# Visa refusal for army assessment

Tags: visas, uk, ghanaian-citizens

My visa was refused and all the necessary documentations were provided but the decisions don't add. So better clarifications are needed. Thanks

[image][image]

Comment: What more do you need? The reasons are laid out in the letter.

Comment: This is a very common refusal. We have dozens of refusals on V 4.2 a+c and sometimes (e) in the archives here.  They got you on funds parking and funds provenance. Honestly, please read the linked article very carefully and whatever you do, don't apply again until this is sorted.

Comment: @GayotFow Perhaps we need a canonical on British Army recruitment refusals for young men from my home country Ghana :-). It never ends

Comment: @SheikPaul working on it